# e.which keycode for minus-hyphen has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running under Ubuntu Linux. I have a JavaScript function that edits data as it is being entered by a user.  The data is edited using the `$,.-+` characters.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/json_sans_eval.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/edit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/cdpUtils.js"></script>
```

```
function onkeypressFunc (event)
{
    var data = event.target.value;
    var keyNum = event.which;
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    var shiftKey = event.shiftKey;
    var charCode = event.charCode;
    if (keyNum == 9 && keyCode == 9) // this works when using keydown
    {
```

I have been testing `keyNum` for months and the <kbd>+</kbd> key has been 43 and the <kbd>-</kbd> key has been 45.
Today I noticed that I can no longer enter a negative number using the <kbd>-</kbd> key on the main keyboard.  After checking, I can see that the `keyNum` code is now 173.  Is there any explanation for the change.  I believe that this same thing occurred several months ago and I had to change the software then to look for the new codes.

This has only been tested on Firefox 22.0.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a bug(at least a compatibility Issues) for firefox, as

```
String.fromCharCode(173)
```

outputs ""

Normally the keypress code is more reliable, e.g. for char '+', you can press shift(16) and =(187) , or the +(107) on the number panel, but the keypress keyCode will always be 43.

Also, as you use jQuery, [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) is prefered.

> event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode